# Verifying accessibility of data members in a multi-level inheritance example in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, access-specifier

I have the following code involving multi-level inheritance in C++.
I want to verify the accessibility of data members for the ***object d*** defined in the *main* in the inheritance chain. I have summarized the accessibility as the following and was wondering if this is how ***object d*** sees its members!

**A:**

a1 public

a2 protected

a3 private

**B:**

A::a1 private

A::a2 private

A::a3 NOT accessible here

b1 public

b2 protected

b3 private

**C:**

A::a1 NOT accessible here

A::a2 NOT accessible here

A::a3 NOT accessible here

B:b1 protected

B:b2 protected

B:b3 NOT accessible here

c1 public

c2 protected

c3 private

**D:**

A::a1 NOT accessible here

A::a2 NOT accessible here

A::a3 NOT accessible here

B:b3 NOT accessible here

B:b1 protected

B:b2 protected

C:c1 public

C:c2 protected

C:c3 NOT accessible here

d1 public

d2 protected

d3 private

```
struct A
{
    A() {}
public:
    int a1;
protected:
    int a2;
private:
    int a3;
};


struct B: private A
{
    B() :
        A() {}
public:
    int b1;
protected:
    int b2;
private:
    int b3;
};


struct C : protected B
{
    C() :
        B() {}
public:
    int c1;
protected:
    int c2;
private:
    int c3;
};


struct D : public C
{
    D() :
        C() {}
public:
    int d1;
protected:
    int d2;
private:
    int d3;
};

int main()
{
    const D d;

}
```

Comment: No pictures of text, please.

Comment: I removed the picture!! but that was more organized!!